# Vue Bootstrap b-table lazy load data

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, vuejs2, nuxt.js, bootstrap-vue

So in the simplest way, I'm using Vue Bootstrap as a framework for my project.

I need to add a custom table to my project, with data that can have thousands of cells (100+ columns and 1k+ rows).

**I don't want to render 100% of the table on component mount. I want to render only the visible data (maybe a little bit more), and as the user scrolls X or Y, more cells will be lazy rendered.**

I would prefer sticking to Boostrap Vue's table rather than having to use an external library just for the table unless it's needed.

What's the best way to achieve this?

Hope you're day is going well!

Comment: You should probably look into a virtual scroller for a dataset of that size or you'll see performance issues quickly.  [For example](https://github.com/Akryum/vue-virtual-scroller)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `items` prop which accepts "items provider function" to fetch data from the remote database. Use pagination and filtering in your API request and only fetch required data like 10 items on each request and render just 10 items in the table.

You can find example in official docs [here](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table#using-items-provider-functions).

Answer (score 0):

I soluce this problem like that.

Firstly, extend Array.prototype like this :

```
Array.prototype.limitTo = function (limit) {
  this.splice(limit, this.length)
  return this
}
```

Secondly, in your v-for dont use directly your items but a computed method like that :

```
<tr v-for="item in limitedItems" ... >
```

In computed section :

```
limitedItems() {
   return this.items.limitTo(this.limit)
},
```

Add a new property in your data section :

```
data() {
  return {
    limit: 25,
    ...
  }
}
```

Then you need to create a wrapper of your table with fixed height and overflow-y: auto like that the scrollY like that :

```
<div ref="wrapper" @scroll="toScroll" style="height:500px;max-height:100%;overflow-y:auto">
  <table ref="content">
    ...
```

In methods section :

```
toScroll() {
   let content = this.$refs['content']
   let wrapper = this.$refs['wrapper']
   if (wrapper.scrollTop + wrapper.offsetHeight + 700 > content.offsetHeight) { // the 700 allow to avoid a little lag when the scroll arrive at end. It allow a preload.
      this.limit += 25 // I had 20-22 rows visible at screen
   }
},
```

Finally, don't forget to reset the limit property to 25 on each reload/refresh/query etc.